# How do I take specific tables from a CSV and write a new file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to take specific tables from a CSV file and return a file for each table. I have something that looks like this:

```
France    city    population    agriculture
France    Paris    2000000      lots
France    Nice     500000      some


England   city    population    agriculture
England   London    30000       none
England   Glasgow    10000      some
```

and I want to return two files, one with

```
France    city    population    agriculture
France    Paris    2000000      lots
France    Nice     500000      some
```

and the other with

```
England   city    population    agriculture
England   London    30000       none
England   Glasgow    10000      some
```

how do I do this?

Comment: Csv python module http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: This is not a really good layout for CSV files.  It would be better to have a header "country" and then have the countries there...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using cvs module (can csv module separate tables?)

```
with open('table.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

tables = text.split('\n\n')

for itable,table in enumerate(tables):
    fileout = 'table%2.2i.txt' % itable
    with open(fileout,'w') as f:
        f.write(table.strip())
```